# CSS Show Image Title below image

Tags: css, title, caption

after upgrading a CMS, i have the problem, that of thousands articles with images, the caption of the image does not shown below the image.

For Example:

```
<img src="123.jpg" alt="Texttext" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" title="Title + Copyright">
```

What can i do, that the title will be displayed as caption below the image?
I have already lot of articles with such images codes and class=caption. So it is not possible, to change the html codes.

But it should be possible to add a CSS, that that caption will be displayed under the image?

Example: https://www.hdsports.at/laufkalender-international

i tried to add a css Code, but without success.

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure to understand why the `title` attribute isn't working to render the caption on hover. Anyway if you can use css only, you may have the chance to use the `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements that unfortunately don't stick to img (because those don't have a closing tag and don't hold a content). So it wouldn't be easy because it would require you have a dummy element semantically connected with each picture, just to add the caption. if you answer to the user above in the comments he will surely help with  js

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, that is impossible using CSS.
if you can't edit the source code, maybe try injecting some javascript code

anyway, here is a code example of putting every title attribute of an image below it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>put title attribute as caption</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class= "caption" title="sample title 1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class= "caption" title="sample title 2"> 
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class= "caption" title="sample title 3"> 
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class= "caption" title="sample title 4">
</body>

<script>
  // get all images that have caption class
  const images = document.getElementsByClassName('caption')
  Object.keys(images).forEach((key) => { 
    // create paragraph HTML tag. it might be span, div, lists and etc. 
    let caption = document.createElement('p');
    // here, we put the title attribute content into a new element we just created
    caption.textContent = images[key]['title'];
    // and finally, we add the caption after each image  
    images[key].after(caption);
  })
</script>
</html>
```

[Try this on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kruyz04b/)

Important: This way you may have SEO issues. Google crawlers may not be able to see the captions you just created.

Comment: Thank you. This works!
How Can i add some styling in the caption? I want a grey background and center the caption text?

Why the google crawlers don't see the caption? But the crawler should see the title-tag?

Comment: @HDsports I'm happy to be of assistance.
1. by using classList you can append a class to the caption. I just update JSFiddle and you can see it.
2. because the caption that have generate using javascript is not part of your source code. that's why crawlers can't see it unless crawlers can render javascript code also.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mta0pg3v/